# Find two vectors $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ that are perpendicular to $(1,0,1)$ and to each other.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Find two vectors $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ that are perpendicular to $(1,0,1)$ and to each other.

It is not to hard to find the particular vectors, but how can i find all vectors, that fit to the problem?

Can you help me please to explain it step by step.
Thank you

Comment: I don't know what you mean.  If you can find $v$ and $w$, then the space of all vectors perpendicular to $(1,0,1)$ will just be $\operatorname{span}(v,w)$.  But the question doesn't appear to ask for that.  It only wants $v$ and $w$.  Are you sure you can find those vectors?

Comment: Does [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137362/how-to-find-perpendicular-vector-to-another-vector?rq=1) help you?  I see your edit but I don't know what you're looking for. The question only asks for two vectors $v$ and $w$ that fit some conditions. If you can find those then you're done. The space of all vectors orthogonal to $(1,0,1)$ is a plane and once you've found $v$ and $w$ that plane will just be $\operatorname{span}(v,w)$. So if you choose any vector in that plane as $v'$ then take the cross product of $v'$ and $(1,0,1)$ to get $w'$ which'll also be solutions..

Comment: The questin was to find  particular vector.
But i want also to know is it possible to find all vectors.
Thanks for the help:)

Comment: $(-1,0,1)$ and $(0,1,0)$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** There is a unique plane in $\mathbb R^3$ to which the given vector ${\mathbf n}=(1,0,1)$ is normal. Just choose any orthogonal basis for the plane.

One way to do this is to rotate $\mathbf n$ through an angle $\pi/2$ in any direction, then form the cross product of the result and the original vector to get a third vector orthogonal to both of the others.

Comment: letting v= (x, y, z), v is orthogonal to (1, 0, 1) if and only if x+ z= 0.  One such vector is (0, 1, 0).  Any vector, (x, y, z) orthogonal to that must satisfy y= 0.  (1, 0, -1) satisfies both so one answer to your question is "(0, 1, 0)  and (1, 0, -1)".  Since those are obviously independent, the two-dimensional space of all such vectors is a(0, 1, 0)+ b(1, 0, -1)= (b, a, -b) for all numbers a and b.